# add ImageListView control to my toolbox in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to add ImageListView in my toolbox of VS2010 ,but I am not able to do so . When I right click on toolbox window -> choose Item option  their I can see ImageListView checkbox selected ,I have also added `ImageListView.dll` file in my project folder but still nothing is working ,what can be the solution to fix this issue
[image: Image shows ImageListView selected and added in >netFramework components]

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem while adding imagelistview.dll in my project. Finally I solved the problem with some solution.

Check your target framework in your project properties. If it is .Net Framework 4.0 client profile then change it to .NetFramework 4.0. And rebuild your project once. Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

ImageListView is now part of the NuGet Package Manager

Install it via the link, and go through the Visual Studio Extension Manager

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget.

When this is downloaded and installed, open your project solution and you should now see the Package Manager Console down the bottom. You the following link to add the tool to your solution:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageListView/